# Show doesn't show all the plots

Tags: plotting

I try to combine three list plots with the `Show` command. Here is the first one:

```
asteroidCount = 
  BinCounts[
   Sort@Cases[(AstronomicalData[#, "SemimajorAxis"]/149597870691) & /@
       Join[AstronomicalData["InnerMainBeltAsteroid"], 
       AstronomicalData["MainBeltAsteroid"], 
       AstronomicalData["OuterMainBeltAsteroid"]], x_?NumberQ], {2, 
    3.5, .005}];
m = ListPlot[asteroidCount, Joined -> True, Filling -> 0, Mesh -> All,
   Ticks -> {Table[{Rescale[x, {2, 3.5}, {0, 301}], x}, {x, 2, 
      3.5, .2}], Automatic}]
```

The second one:

```
omega[a_] := 2 Pi/a^(3/2);
k = ListPlot[
  Flatten[Table[{a /. FindRoot[omega[a]/omega[5.2] == j/i, {a, 1}], 
     700}, {j, 5, 6, 1}, {i, 1, 5, 1}], 1], Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, 800}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Black, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Red},
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Black, 
    Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(J\)]\)", {5.2, 1}], 
    Point[{5.2, 0.1}]
    }]
```

And finally the third one:

```
l = ListPlot[
  Flatten[Table[{a /. FindRoot[omega[a]/omega[5.2] == j/i, {a, 1}], 
     700}, {j, 1, 5, 1}, {i, 5, 6, 1}], 1], Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, 800}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Black, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Red},
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Black, 
    Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(J\)]\)", {5.2, 1}], 
    Point[{5.2, 0.1}]
    }]
```

When I use `Show[k,l,m]` I see only the last two plots (`l` and `m`) and I don't know why... Can someone help me please?

Comment: steroidCount in the first line should be asteroidCount. I attempted to edit but it said that an edit had to be at least six characters.

Comment: @JonathanShock fixed, and I moved the definition for `omega` above `k` as it depends on it, also.

Comment: It also seems that you are loading the astronomical data on the order of 50000 times to get the initial asteroiodcount. Can you show us the individual plots to see what the problem might be in `Show`?

Comment: @JonathanShock about to put up an answer, and adding the pictures won't illustrate the problem.

Comment: @JonathanShock it's up, if you want to see the explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply, they are not on the same scale. Modifying the `Ticks` of `m` gives the illusion that they are, but that is for display, only, and does not reflect the true x-axis found in `m`. If you extract the display options, like this

```
m /. Graphics[___, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :> Flatten@{opt}
```

you get

```
PlotRange -> {{0, 300.}, {0, 540.}}
```

among others. So, the x-axis actually goes from 0 to 300 because the data only consists of y-values.  To truly change the range of the x-axis, you need to use [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DataRange.html), as follows

```
m = ListPlot[asteroidCount, Joined -> True, Filling -> 0, Mesh -> All,
   DataRange -> {2, 3.5}]
```

[image]

The ranges of the combined pictures are still not completely compatible, but they can be fully displayed using

```
Show[{m, k, l}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot for this helpfull answer !!!!