# Show function doesn't plot two graphics

Tags: plotting

I've got a following code snippet:

```
olddatafile := "~/git/hpx/old_serialization_generated_data";
newdatafile := "~/git/hpx/new_serialization_generated_data";

oldplot := 
 ListPlot[ReadList[olddatafile, {Number, Number}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{Style["Boost", FontSize -> 20]}, {Left, Top}], 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]
newplot := 
 ListPlot[ReadList[newdatafile, {Number, Number}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{Style["HPX", FontSize -> 20]}, {Left, Top}],  
  PlotStyle -> Red]

Show[oldplot, newplot, ImageSize -> Full, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["from 1 to 100 data size", FontSize -> 30], 
 AxesLabel -> {"data_size", "seconds"}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], GridLines -> Automatic]
```

I expect it to show me two different plots (like it did before), but I get only first one. I made sure that DataRange option is the same for both plots (like it was answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21374/show-doesnt-show-all-the-plots)). If I don't combine them with Show, plots are displayed well separately.

Here are values of olddatafile and newdatafile:

```
ReadList[olddatafile, {Number, Number}]

In[80]:= {{1, 0.00863999`}, {5, 0.00885776`}, {10, 0.00879894`}, {15, 
  0.0100123`}, {20, 0.00951515`}, {25, 0.00941007`}, {30, 
  0.00924682`}, {35, 0.0094212`}, {40, 0.0096916`}, {45, 
  0.00955581`}, {50, 0.00988706`}, {55, 0.00977177`}, {60, 
  0.0100432`}, {65, 0.0105198`}, {70, 0.0106113`}, {75, 
  0.0108512`}, {80, 0.0106733`}, {85, 0.0104314`}, {90, 
  0.010475`}, {95, 0.0106352`}, {100, 0.0121299`}}
ReadList[newdatafile, {Number, Number}]

Out[81]= {{1, 0.00332785}, {5, 0.00347605}, {10, 0.00385404}, {15, 
  0.00388163}, {20, 0.00406281}, {25, 0.00425853}, {30, 
  0.00418382}, {35, 0.00465427}, {40, 0.00520275}, {45, 
  0.00479219}, {50, 0.00496409}, {55, 0.00505981}, {60, 
  0.00518383}, {65, 0.00560755}, {70, 0.00557286}, {75, 
  0.00571052}, {80, 0.0055853}, {85, 0.0053877}, {90, 
  0.00598863}, {95, 0.00580467}, {100, 0.00602062}}
```

Comment: Can't read the data from your files. Can you make something self-contained - maybe plot random numbers or something?

Comment: @bills oh yes, just added them

Comment: Options are inherited from the first plot.  Try PlotRange -> All in Show.  I didn't run your code, just guessing.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it works, thanks!

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128/plot-option-precedence-while-combining-plots-with-show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
 ListPlot[{olddatafile, newdatafile},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
 Joined -> True,
 ImageSize -> Full, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["from 1 to 100 data size", FontSize -> 30], 
 AxesLabel -> {"data_size", "seconds"}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends ->
  {Placed[{Style["HPX", FontSize -> 20, Red]}, {Left, Top}],
   Placed[{Style["Boost", FontSize -> 20, Blue]}, {Left, Top}]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks, man